# What makes the following expression produce a wrong rotated point?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

I want to rotate point `B` 30 degrees counterclockwise about `A` to produce a new point `C`. However, I failed to get the correct `C` as illustrated below. The red circle helps us to notice the issue easily.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{saveNodeCoors}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,6)
    \pstGeonode
        (1,1){A}
        (5,3){B}
        (!N-B.y N-A.y sub 2 exp  N-B.x N-A.x sub 2 exp add sqrt N-B.y N-A.y sub N-B.x N-A.x sub atan 30 add PtoC){C}
    \pstCircleOA[linecolor=red]{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes

Don't suggest me to use `\pstRotation` as I already know it and it is not my interest. You might suggest me to use `([angle=30,nodesep=]{B}A)`, but the problem is that  `nodesep` must be assigned with an absolute value. It might be a good idea to add a new key, for example, `relnodesep` to `([angle=30,...]{B}A)` syntax so we can solve this problem by just writing `([angle=30,relnodesep=1]{B}A)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only rotate the difference vector between node `A` and `B`, but at the end you must add the coordinates of the 'origin' `A`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{saveNodeCoors}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,6)
    \pstGeonode
        (1,1){A}
        (5,3){B}
        (!N-B.y N-A.y sub 2 exp  N-B.x N-A.x sub 2 exp add sqrt 
          N-B.y N-A.y sub N-B.x N-A.x sub atan 30 add PtoC 
          N-A.y add exch N-A.x add exch % this was missing
        ){C}
    \pstCircleOA[linecolor=red]{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my ghost, I forgot it.